# Failing to configure local box as wifi hotspot with nmcli

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, networkmanager, wireless-hotspot

I am trying to configure my Fedora 38 box to work as an access point (WiFi hotspot) called, say, `MyAP`.

So I use `nmcli` like this:

```
nmcli -p con add type wifi con-name MyAP autoconnect yes ssid MyAp \
   ipv6.method disabled ipv4.method shared ipv4.addresses 192.168.66.1/24 \
   gw4 192.168.66.1 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless.band a \
   wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk <somepassword>
```

Yet, `MyAP` keeps connecting/disconnecting several times. In this case, `nmcli dev status` shows:

```
DEVICE             TYPE      STATE                     CONNECTION   
enp0s31f6          ethernet  connected                 IMPA Wired   
wlp0s20f3          wifi      connecting (configuring)  MyAP 
p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3  wifi-p2p  disconnected              --           
lo                 loopback  unmanaged                 --
```

and it stays like that: `connecting (configuring)` in yellow. The command `nmcli c` shows `MyAP` connection in yellow.

In `journalctl -b` I see these:

```
NetworkManager[1042]: <warn>  [1690232848.2272] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) Hotspot network creation took too long, failing activation
NetworkManager[1042]: <info>  [1690232848.2272] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
wpa_supplicant[19218]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
NetworkManager[1042]: <warn>  [1690232848.2281] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: failed for connection 'MyAP'
NetworkManager[1042]: <info>  [1690232848.2285] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[1042]: <info>  [1690232848.2416] device (wlp0s20f3): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 9E:45:F9:B7:73:84 (scanning)
NetworkManager[1042]: <info>  [1690232848.2614] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
NetworkManager[1042]: <info>  [1690232848.2614] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
```

Why `MyAP` is not connecting?

**EDIT**

It seems that it works if I remove the band restriction `802-11-wireless.band a`. Strange, because it used to work with this.